Get count of column based on condition inside JSON
Requirement is to get count of column based on condition inside JSON string
string jsonString = """{"data":"key = IAfpK, age = 58, key = WNVdi, age = 64"}""";

Condition age >= 50
Count of Age = 2
Option 1
I tried to deserialize JSON to a model first
public class JsonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(s);

List<JsonModel> result = items.Where(x => x.Age >= 50).ToList();// doesnt work

Console.WriteLine(result.Count());

Option 2
        dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(s);
        var a = obj.data[0]; //Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.'
        string error = a.age;

Option 3
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(s);
    var a = obj.data["age"]; //Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.'
    

Tried few options it's not working, how do I get the count?
Option 4
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
       
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var s = await client.GetStringAsync("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting");
        var jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(s);


 foreach (var package in jsonLinq)
        {
            string[] values = package.Value.ToString().Split(',');
            //var res = values.Where(String.Format("age=50"));

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.AddRange(values);
            
        }
           }


jsonString is invalid JSON. So that is the reason you are having issues. Can you fix the format? Or are you stuck with that?

data propety is string, which contains comma separated assignments. Not really usable JSON.

@baynezy The actual Json is
{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64"} unable to add it to string string data = @"{"data":"key = IAfpK, age = 58, key = WNVdi, age = 64"}"; so thats why added in single quotes

@SvyatoslavDanyliv When I paste it to json beautifer then no error
The actual json is coming from this links
https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting

@Dave - you used a single quote to delimit strings, but that is not actually allowed by the JSON standard.  It's something Json.NET supports as an extension to the standard but other parsers such as System.Text.Json will reject.

Your problem is that the value of the data string in the JSON {"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64"} is not itself well-formed embedded JSON, so you can't use a JSON parser to extract its keys and values.  You will need to adopt a different approach to parse that string.

@baynezy I have added Option 4 where I am splitting the string and need to filter the count based on age thats giving a issue.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv  have added Option 4 where I am splitting the string and need to filter the count based on age thats giving a issue.

@dbc Please check Option 4 I have parsed it and extracted Value. So now I have "key=IFV" "age=58" "key=IFCC" "age=50" need to get the count of age where age >=50

@Dave In Option 4 what is jsonLinq?

@RahulSharma I have corrected Option 4 by adding the whole code.

I formatted the Json string as Raw string literal. But the condition part is still one single Json string. Therefore, you cannot deserialize it as array of objects or key/value pairs.

You should split data property string value and parse by yourself.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var jsonStr = await client.GetStringAsync("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting");
    var parsed = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonStr);
    var dataString = parsed.RootElement.GetProperty("data").GetString();

    if (dataString != null)
    {
        var pairs = dataString.Split(", ");
        var items = new List<(string Key, int Age)>();

        for (var index = 0; index < pairs.Length; index += 2)
        {
            if (index + 1 >= pairs.Length)
                break;

            var firstPair = pairs[index].Split("=");
            var secondPair = pairs[index + 1].Split("=");

            if (firstPair.Length != 2 || secondPair.Length != 2)
                continue;

            if (firstPair[0] != "key" || secondPair[0] != "age")
                continue;

            items.Add((Key: firstPair[1], Age: int.Parse(secondPair[1])));
        }

        var count = items.Count(x => x.Age >= 50);
    }
}


Thanks but Chunk and TrimEntries are not detecting in my console which name spcaes you have used.

@RahulSharma Tried still doesn't detects.

@Dave Which compiler version are you using?

@RahulSharma Its a console app in netcoreapp3.0 version, is it working in your machine.

Which Traget Framework do you have?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv .NetCore3.0

@Dave, check new version.
